# When i merge two data frames by ID's i do not get ID's for one of the data frames

Tags: r

I have two data frames: w2p and EUpb.

I merged the two data frames by 'Sample.ID' and  i wanted to create a column in the merged data frame that specifies the source of each observation (either w2p or EUpb).

I executed the following code and it worked:

```
w2p$source <- "w2p"
EUpb$source <- "EUPb"
Merged <- merge(x = w2p, y = EUpb,
            all = TRUE, by = c("Sample.ID"))
Merged$rowSource <- apply(Merged[c("source.x", "source.y")], 1, 
                      function(x) paste(na.omit(x), collapse = ""))
```

However, the Sample.ID does not show for EUPb in the merged data frame and i am unsure as to why that is the case. I merged by sample ID and set all=TRUE. See below:

The merged data frame consists of 3575 obs of 168 variables. Here is a little snippet of a few rows showing missing Sample.ID's for EUPb.

```
rowSource  Sample.ID 
w2p         ZB01/2
w2p         ZD-702/3
w2p         ZD-703/2
EUPb        NA
EUPb        NA
EUPb        NA
```

Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you need merge? Do the sample IDs appear in both dataframes? It looks like you just need to rbind the two dataframes.

Comment: Also, consider using coalesce instead: `merged$rowSource<-coalesce(merged$source.x,merged$source.y)`

Comment: Yes the sample ID's do appear in both data frames. The two data frames have different variables though. That is the reason i used merged.

Comment: Then how come you either have w2p OR EUPb in the combined rowSource?

Comment: So there are rows where the rowSource is w2pEUpb implying that the Sample.ID is common in both data frames.

Comment: coalesce does not seem to work

Answer (score 1):

I like to add `source` to one of the frames before doing any merging, as those rows attributed to the first frame will be identified as such and the second frame's rows will be `NA`:

```r
df1 <- data.frame(id = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L))
df2 <- data.frame(id = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 5L))

merged <- merge(transform(df1, source = "df1", stringsAsFactors = FALSE),
                df2, by="id", all=TRUE)
merged
#   id source
# 1  1    df1
# 2  2    df1
# 3  3    df1
# 4  4    df1
# 5  5   <NA>
merged$source <- ifelse(is.na(merged$source), "df2", merged$source)
merged
#   id source
# 1  1    df1
# 2  2    df1
# 3  3    df1
# 4  4    df1
# 5  5    df2
```

---

`dplyr` alternative, this time defining `source` in both frames beforehand and `coalesce`ing it afterwards.

```r
library(dplyr)
full_join(
  mutate(df1, source = "df1"),
  mutate(df2, source = "df2"),
  by = "id"
) %>%
  mutate(source = coalesce(source.x, source.y)) %>%
  select(-source.x, -source.y)
#   id source
# 1  1    df1
# 2  2    df1
# 3  3    df1
# 4  4    df1
# 5  5    df2
```

Comment: I get the following error: Error in UseMethod("mutate_") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate_' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"

Comment: Do i need to change the columns into numeric?

Comment: I have *no idea* how your data is actually structured. The only way to answer that with confidence is if you add the output from `dput(head(EUpb))` (and for `w2p`) to your question; that's one of the better ways to show an unambiguous data sample. (You can subset the columns shown to what is relevant ... but the `dput` part is important.)